# Regex Capture between a delimiter

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following regex

```
^.*(?<width>\d*)x(?<height>\d*).*$
```

and want to parse this string so I can get the width and height within in but can only capture the height.  What am I doing wrong with my capture?

```
iPhone (320x50 pt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `.*` is too greedy and matches too much (everything up to `x` - because `\d*` allows for an empty string to be matched). You can use non greedy `.*?`:

```
^.*?(?<width>\d*)x(?<height>\d*).*$
```

Alternatively, match non-digits in the first part:

```
^[^\d]*(?<width>\d*)x(?<height>\d*).*$
```

If the width is always preceded by `(`, you can just specify it:

```
^.*\((?<width>\d*)x(?<height>\d*).*$
```

There's multiple possibilities here and it all depends on the strings that you try to match. It's hard to say from only one example which approach would work best for you.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because your first .* is greedy and captures everything until the x, since you allow 0-n digits.

So I see two fast replacements:

```
^\D*(?<width>\d*)x(?<height>\d*)\D*$
```

would search for non-Digits before the width

you can also do

```
^.*?(?<width>\d*)x(?<height>\d*).*?$
```

which would be a non-greedy search.

Check this attempt on https://regex101.com/r/lD7aA0/1